# Javascript Income tax calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I was hoping somebody could take a quick look at this and give me some pointers on what I am doing wrong. I tried to follow a tip calculator program I found on JS Fiddle and it worked up to the point where I tried performing the calculation.

Any tips would be helpful!

Thanks!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Shibi/pg6hg7hg/63/

HTML:

```
<form id="calculator" method="post">

<div>
<p><input value="" id="income"></input></p>

</div>

<select id="states" onchange="changetax(this)">
  <option>Choose state</option>
  <option value="0.4">Alabama</option>
  <option value="0">Alaska</option>
  <option value="0.56">Arizona</option>
  <option value="0.65">Arkansas</option>
</select>   
<div id="tax"></div>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
   <hr />

<p>Taxed Amount: <div id="tax"></div></p>
<p>Total: <div id="total"></div></p>


</form>
```

JS:

```
function changetax($this){

   $("#tax").text($this.value>0?("Income Tax: " + $this.value + "%") : "");
}

function calculate() {

var income = $('#income').val();
var tax = $('#tax').val();
var taxedAmount = income*tax;
var total = income - taxedAmount;

}

$('#calculator').submit( calculate );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 issues immediately.

1. Your div and your input both have an ID of 'income', ID's are supposed to be unique.
2. You are doing math on "strings", either parse them to int with parseInt() or times the value by 1 (val*1) to get a good number.

Here is an example of using the (val*1) and parseInt() with very generic validation.

```
function changetax($this){

   $("#tax").text($this.value>0?("Income Tax: " + $this.value + "%") : "");
}

function calculate() {

var incomestr = $('#income').val();
var taxstr = $('#tax').val();

 // convert values to int
var income = (incomestr*1);    
var tax = parseInt(taxstr);

if(income > 0 && tax > 0){    
var taxedAmount = income*tax;
var total = income - taxedAmount;
}

}

$('#calculator').submit( calculate );
```

**Edit:**

Ok I will leave the above example but here is a working example of what you were trying to do. I had to change up a few things.

1. You had 'tax' and 'income' ids in 2 places, I left only one of each.
2. You were trying to .val() divs, you can use .text() instead, .val() only works on elements with a value attribute.
3. Your "Income Tax: .." string was in your 'tax' id, which is not a number, I changed the tax field to 'taxed' and pointed the value there.
4. Your tax values actually existed on your 'states' id so I updated the tax variable to look at states value instead.
5. Your fiddle didnt work as its posting a form, I removed the submit and made it an event so it can work for demonstration.
6. Try using spans for text values where possible, divs are block elements and you will run into issues with layout in the future, though it has no bearing on this example just a note.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lookitstony/chn3t025/

Html:

```
<div>
    <p><input value="" id="income"></input></p>    
</div>

<select id="states" onchange="changetax(this)">
  <option>Choose state</option>
    <option value="0.4">Alabama</option>
    <option value="0">Alaska</option>
    <option value="0.56">Arizona</option>
    <option value="0.65">Arkansas</option>
</select>

<div id="tax"></div>  
<p><button id="calculator">Calculate</button></p>

<hr />

<p>Taxed Amount: <span id="taxed"></span></p>
<p>Total: <span id="total"></span></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function changetax($this){

   $("#tax").text($this.value>0?("Income Tax: " + $this.value + "%") : "");
}

function calculate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var income = $('#income').val();
    var tax = $('#states').val();
    var taxedAmount = income*tax;
    var total = income - taxedAmount;
    $('#taxed').text(taxedAmount);
    $('#total').text(total);
    return false;
}
$(function(){
$('#calculator').click( calculate );
});
```

Almost forgot this, I try linking to it in every JS question I answer as it has made major impact on my JS skills. Here are some design patterns that will save your life. http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Could you please elaborate on how I would go about using parseInt() or (val*1) for these particular variables ?

Comment: @Shibi, i've updated the answer. The big problem with not converting and making sure they are ints can really be seen when using addition. It will concat your numbers instead of adding them but I still like to validate I am dealing with a number before performing math on a user input. you might also find this plugin helpful, i do. http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful, I'll definitely check out that plugin.

I did what you said and I still somehow get a Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed Error. Any idea why ? Everything else seems to be fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Shibi/pg6hg7hg/63/

Comment: @Shibi, the 403 is because you were using a form and trying to post the data. check this link for more information on CSRF errors. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that stands out to me is that you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute; this will mean that when you do things like `$('#income').val()`, you may be selecting the `div` with that ID instead of the input, which is what you want.

Make sure IDs are always unique.